# Change component characteristics (style) using a loop

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there anyway to go through each component(Ex: button/label) characteristics using an infinite loop? In my app I have 24 buttons in a particular screen and I want to change color of each button one by one all the time. I want to change the color of each button one by one all the time. I have tried both `componentdidmount` and `componentwillmount`, but it happens once. When I go to another screen and come back, the loop doesnt start.[image]

Comment: What triggers each loop iteration? Time? A user action?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I want to trigger the loop when the user go to that particular screen only

Comment: Right, but what triggers each loop *iteration*?

Comment: I need to trigger each iteration automatically

Comment: Please make an effort to write a good question to avoid it being closed, you are far more likely to get a useful answer if your question is very clear.  please review how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on a timed interval, you'd keep track of the selected item in your state, e.g.:

```
// In your constructor (since you mentioned `componentDidMount`, I know you're using classes)
this.state = {
    selectedControl: 0,
    // ...your other state
};
```

In `componentDidMount`, start your interval timer:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerHandle = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(({selectedControl, controls}) =>
           ({selectedControl: (selectedControl + 1) % controls.length})
        );
    }, 2000); // 2000ms = two seconds
}
```

When rendering the controls, highlight the selected one:

```
render() {
    const {selectedControl, controls} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {controls.map((control, index) => (
                <input key={index} type="button" value={control} className={index === selectedControl ? "highlighted" : undefined} />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Note that in all of that I've assumed `this.state.controls` is an array of your controls.

Adjust as necessary, that's just to get you headed the right way.

Live Example (going a bit faster than 2 seconds):

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // In your constructor (since you mentioned `componentDidMount`, I know you're using classes)
        this.state = {
            selectedControl: 0,
            controls: ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerHandle = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(({selectedControl, controls}) =>
               ({selectedControl: (selectedControl + 1) % controls.length})
            );
        }, 800); // 800ms = 0.8 seconds
    }

    render() {
        const {selectedControl, controls} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {controls.map((control, index) => (
                    <input key={index} type="button" value={control} className={index === selectedControl ? "highlighted" : undefined} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.highlighted {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the exact thing what I've been looking for, Thanks!